# iTunes won't sync podcasts in folder

Tags: itunes

I have some podcasts that I've put in a playlist, the playlist is supposed to sync with my iPhone - however when I try to sync with my iPhone, the podcasts doesn't sync.

I suppose this has something to do with my Podcast syncing options, options that are working well for me, so I don't want to change them.

Is there a way to tell iTunes that a podcast is no longer a podcast, but merely an audio file? I've tried to change the genre to no luck.

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 1):

I went into the podcasts tab at the top and had to select 'sync podcasts automatically' before mine would start working. Hope this works for others too!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently.

I fixed it by deselecting the problem podcasts, syncing, then selecting them again. After this, the podcasts transferred correctly to the iPhone, and have synced happily since then.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  You have to go into your device menu in iTunes (not the library page showing what you've got.)  Then click on Podcasts on the left.  Then in the big page on the right you should select automatically sync podcasts, but then the big issue is scroll way down on that page and you have to actually tick the box on the playlists you want to appear and sync.